# Trying to show a value and description in Jquery UI Autocomplete, not showing data, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery, webmethod

I have been all over looking to try and solve my issue.  I am thinking it may be on my back end but not sure.  I am trying to use autocomplete to fill in a textbox but show in the drop down a description with the value.

**My Method for grabbing the Data:**

```
[WebMethod]
public static ArrayList GetQueries(string id)
{
    queries q;
    var cs = Global.CS; 
    var con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    var da = new SqlDataAdapter(querystring, con);
    var dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    ArrayList rows = new ArrayList(dt.Rows.Count);
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var val = dt.Rows[i]["Query_ID"];
        var des = dt.Rows[i]["Description"];

        q = new queries();
        q.label = val.ToString();
        q.value = val.ToString() + " -- " + des.ToString();

        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(q);

        rows.Add(json);
    }
    return rows;
}

public class queries
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

It is returning an arraylist.

**My JQuery Method to get data and autocomplete.**

```
$("[id$=QueryManager]").change(function () {
    var id = $("[id$=QueryManager] :selected").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Upload.aspx/GetQueries',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            fillit(data);
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert('Request Status: ' + ex.status + '\n\nStatus Text: ' + ex.statusText + '\n\n' + ex.responseText);
        }
    });
});

    function fillit(data) {
        $("#QueryTxt").autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: function (data, response) {                
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.label,
                        value: item.value
                    }
                }));
            }                
        });
    };
```

I have tried it with both the serialize and without to no results.  When this code runs it shows that autocomplete is working (via the box showing up below) but there is no data in it.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have mix them up. Follow what is on the tutorial http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: Telling me I have mixed them up does not help.  I have been over that and am still confused as to why this does not work.  I am not well experienced with jquery so I cannot tell what most of that is doing.

Comment: The fillit, must not called that way, the `$("#QueryTxt").autocomplete({` must called on window load, then the data must get them when the autocomplete needs them. Get the example for autocomplete as it is.

Comment: Both are in an autoload.  And I have tried using the example they provided with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm doing below is that on the "Select" event I take the values returned from the query and set the text of the drop down to the description and Id value from the data brought back. Then I set a dummy textbox's value as the description. "colDescName" is just a variable I was using as my textbox id.

> ```
>     $("#" +colDescName).autocomplete({
>                 minLength: 2,
>                     select: function( event, ui ) 
>                     {
>                         var rowElement=event.target.id;//Drop down Id
>                         setTimeout(function()
>                         {
>                               $("#"+rowElement).val(ui.item.value+':'+ui.item.id)
>                         },100);//need a slight delay here to set the value
>                         $("#TextBoxId").val(ui.item.value);
>                         //ui.item.value  is the description in the drop down.
>                         //ui.item.id  is the Id value from the drop down
>                     },
>                 source: function (request, response) {
>                     var term = request.term;
>                     if (term in cache) {
>                         response(cache[term]);
>                         return;
>                     }
>                     lastXhr = $.getJSON("Upload.aspx/GetQueries", request, function (data, status, xhr) {
>                         cache[term] = data;
>                         if (xhr === lastXhr) {
>                             response(data);
>                         }
>                     }).error(function () {
>                         console.log("error"); 
>                         }); 
>                 } 
>             });
> ```

What object is "$("[id$=QueryManager]")" that you have the change method on? Would you need the change event if you can use the above code?

**EDIT**
OK an easier way is set your textbox "$("#QueryTxt")" to an autocomplete box before executing any change events on your "QueryManager" manager dropdown. Then when a change event does occur in your  "QueryManager" , call:

> $(this).autocomplete('search', 'your data here');

That will then execute the search function and call the autocomplete's url with your required data

Comment: It is a drop down list and will send an ajax call to the back end with the value of that box which will determine the search parameters of the autocomplete data.  Making this autocomplete happen if they change the selection.

Comment: Is the way to wrote this for a dropdown list or for a text input?

Comment: Hey bags, big time difference here, was asleep already hence my delayed answered. "$(this).autocomplete('search', 'your data here');" above will be for your text input which will be triggered from the change event in your drop down with id of "QueryManager" so make your text input already has been setup as a autocomplete